# ASCII return character within Javascript within Python shows up as a line feed and "unterminated string error"

Tags: javascript, python, escaping, ascii

I have a Python script which generates an HTLM page that contains Javascript.

In Python, I define a string that contains the Javascript.

The Javascript needs to define a Return character.

I tried 3 different ways:

```
ScriptHTML = """
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RetChar = '\x0D';
    var RetChar2 = '\r';
    var RetChar3 = '\\\r';

    var MyString1 = 'ABC' + RetChar;
    var MyString2 = '123' + RetChar;

</script>
"""

def Main():
    print "Content-type: text/html\n"
    print ScriptHTML
```

When I look at the generated HTML, I see that the return has been interpreted to mean: put a line feed between the quotes.

```
var RetChar = '
'
var RetChar2 = '
'
var RetChar3 = '
'
```

Which gets me the Javascript error:

```
"SyntaxError: unterminated string literal"
```

How can I solve this?

I also need a solution for a TAB character, please.

Comment: It is converting them directly into the output you can use `String.fromCharCode()` to convert it via ascii values or do `\\r` the double slash should escape only the slash and the r should print normally to code which would then be escaped only in javascript.

Comment: String.fromCharCode(13) worked. Please post it as an answer, so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a raw string literal which keeps the escape codes from being processed by Python.

```
ScriptHTML = r"""
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RetChar = '\r';
    var MyString1 = 'ABC' + RetChar;
    var MyString2 = '123' + RetChar;

</script>
"""

def Main():
    print "Content-type: text/html\n"
    print ScriptHTML
```

You can also easily add a tab character by putting `var TabChar = '\t'` after the definition of `RetChar`.

Comment: That works as well, thank you. I prefer your solution to MiltoxBeyond's, so I'll mark yours as accepted.